# Loglog plot with linear ticks on x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

So I have this data I'd like plotted on `loglog` scale, with linear values on the y-axis and the values in dB on the x axis and

```
loglog(EbN0,BER)
```

outputs a nice looking curve, but the problem is the axis ticks. It's fine on the y-axis, but the x axis only has one tick, at `10^0`and no other ticks. Furthermore, that tick corresponds to the absolute value, not the dB value. Any convenient way to accomplish this?

(Note that both EbN0 and BER contain absolute values)

EDIT: I'll add my data and explain what I want a bit more.

```
EbN0 =

  Columns 1 through 14

0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000    3.0000    3.5000    4.0000    4.5000    5.0000    5.5000    6.0000    6.5000    7.0000

  Columns 15 through 20

7.5000    8.0000    8.5000    9.0000    9.5000   10.0000

BER_TOT_ITER =

  Columns 1 through 14

    0.2928    0.2024    0.1183    0.0511    0.0164    0.0046    0.0010    0.0003    0.0001         0    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0

  Columns 15 through 20

         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

If I do `plot(10*log10(EbN0),10*log10(BER_TOT_ITER))`, I actually get exactly the graph I want and the dB values on the x axis, but now the y ticks are displayed in dB's instead of absolute values... so I just want to relabel the y ticks, NOT rescale the figure.

Comment: you can set the xtick intervals by something like `set(gca,'Xtick',someRange:someRange or [tick1,tick2,tick3...tickn])`

Comment: Which version of MATLAB (or `HG`) are you using?

Comment: I would suggest GameOfThrows' method, and have `someRange` depend on `XLim`. When plotting, save a handle to the line(s) using `hF = loglog(EbN0,BER)` then adjust `hF.XTick = ...` according to your needs. We could be of more help if you upload some sample data.

Comment: As I interpret your comments, set(gca,'Ytick',EbN0) should do the trick if I want to convert from dB to linear ticks, but it doesn't. Am I getting this right?

Comment: If you want to convert it back to linear ticks you need to apply the dB to linear math function on EbN0 - i.e. set(gca,'Ytick',10*log(EbNo))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relabeling the ticks is really the wrong approach here. You'd replace numerical values with strings and resizing etc. wouldn't work anymore.
Also your data does not fit to what you're actually looking at.
You should always try to transform your data first.

So besides `loglog` have a look at [**`semilogx`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html) and [**`semilogy`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html), which allow you to have a single logarithmic axis.

To sum up, what you're looking for is:

```
semilogy(10*log10(EbN0), BER_TOT_ITER)
```

Comment: True - I think this is the right way, but in answer to the question - the OP did ask how to format the ticks, which is why I was commenting on how to format the Xticks.

Comment: @GameOfThrows he asked, because he didn't know about `semiloxy` ;)